# ColdFusion handling AJAX JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I am setting up a local API as an additional step in my external API call using AJAX. The sequence goes like this:

- Ajax call passes data to localAPI.cfm.
- Inside localAPI.cfm I have `<cfhttp>` to send the data to an external api.

However, after I pass the data to `localAPI.cfm` via ajax how do I target(grab) the data?

Here is the ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "MODULES/PAGES/API/localAPI.cfm",
      // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
      data: JSON.stringify(SDdata),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {}
   });
```

inside `localAPI.cfm`:

```
<cfhttp url = "http://<cfoutput>#PageAPILocation#</cfoutput>" method = "POST" result="result">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="##"/>
</cfhttp>
<cftry>
    <cfset ReturnedData = deserializeJSON(result.FileContent)>
    <cfcatch>
      <cfdump var="#result#" />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I know I'm missing something, once I can figure out how to grab the data being passed via AJAX I will place it in the `cfhttpparam` value.

Here is whats being passed:

```
{FunctionName: "PlanList", APIkey: "12345", PageNumber: "1", MaxRows: "10", ReturnType: "json"}
  APIkey:"12345"
  FunctionName:"PlanList"
  MaxRows:"10"
  PageNumber:"1"
  ReturnType:"json"
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you may want to look into getHttpRequestData().  From there, you would use deserializeJSON() to get to the data sent to the cfm by the AJAX call.

Comment: @snackboy you got it! that worked, can you answer the question so i can give you credit :)

Comment: As an aside, using .cfc's instead of .cfm scripts typically makes ajax tasks like this a lot easier. Just define the appropriate arguments and they can be accessed by name within the function, ie `arguments.variableName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into `getHttpRequestData()`. From there, you would use `deserializeJSON()` to get to the data sent to the cfm by the AJAX call.